# UIAlertView Login and Password

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I'm having trouble using a login and password with my alert. Below is my code for my .h and .m files.

.h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

UITextField *textField;
UITextField *textField2;
NSString *login;
NSString *password;
```

}

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

login = @"login";
password = @"password";

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField2 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
alert.tag = 0;
[alert show]; 
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (alertView.tag == 0 && buttonIndex == 1) {
    NSLog(@"Button 2 was pressed");
    if (textField.text == login && textField2.text == password) {
        NSLog(@"Correct login and password");
    }
}

}
```

I get the NSLog saying that "Button 2 was pressed" but I am not getting the NSLog saying "Correct login and password". I am very new to alerts with text fields and would greatly appreciate any help to the proper way to go about it. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: see my updated answer. Its have checked its working.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
 if (textField.text == login && textField2.text == password)
```

with

```
 if ([textField.text isEqualtoString:login] && [textField2.text isEqualToString:password])
```

You can't compare strings for equality with `==` because it compares addresses in memory, not actual objects. `NSString *` is a POINTER, remember that

Answer (score 1):

```
use following code in clickedButtonAtIndex

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (alertView.tag == 0 && buttonIndex == 1) {
    UITextField *text1 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    UITextField *text2 = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"Button 2 was pressed");
    if ([text1.text isEqualToString:login] && [text2.text isEqualToString:password]) {
        NSLog(@"Correct login and password");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the wrong condition there. Remember that you are checking alert textfield so you have to check like this :

Here is full working code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    login = @"login";
    password = @"password";

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    alert.tag = 0;
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alert.tag == 0 && buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Button 2 was pressed");
        if ([[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqualToString:login] && [[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].text isEqualToString:password]) {
            NSLog(@"Correct login and password");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.